# Purpose of SLACcitation field

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I'm working with BibTeX generated by InspireHEP, which includes a SLACcitation field (which looks to be REVTeX specific).

When I render this MWE, the SLACcitation does not show up anywhere. Are there styles that do use the field? Is it required in REVTeX? Is there documentation on its use?

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Purrer:2015tud,
      author         = "Pürrer, Michael",
      title          = "{Frequency domain reduced order model of aligned-spin
                        effective-one-body waveforms with generic mass-ratios and
                        spins}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev.",
      volume         = "D93",
      year           = "2016",
      number         = "6",
      pages          = "064041",
      doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.93.064041",
      eprint         = "1512.02248",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1512.02248;%%"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: what's below was based on a syntax error of mine; you can safely ignore what's below but I'm leaving it in so the comments below make sense.

<s>On a side note, when I change the quotes around the fields to braces, they are accepted for all but the SLACcitation field; it looks like the percentage signs are interpreted differently inside quotes vs braces. Yet Tame the BeaST says</s>

> <s>Values (i.e. right hand sides of each assignment) can be either between curly braces or between double quotes. The main difference is that you can write double quotes in the first case, and not in the  second case.</s>

Are there more differences between quotes and braces?

Comment: On my installation only REVTeX styles print the field. I found https://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hep/refs/bibstyles.shtml

Comment: At least in my tests I could not find a difference between `"..."` and `{...}` for `SLACcitation`. Did you get different behaviour? If so, how did the behaviour differ? As far as I can see the information is just written as is in a new line to the `.bbl` file, but since it starts with `%%` it is ignored in the output. I guess it is supposed to be some kind of metadata for citation analysis.

Comment: See https://web.archive.org/web/20041026075722/http://www.slac.stanford.edu:80/spires/hep/latex.html

Comment: I would never have found that -- thanks. So, this applies to both bibtex and biblatex. I've tried getting the MWE at https://www.overleaf.com/4345765536fmvztnsjxqtx to render the SLACcitation but none of the styles I tried were found at Overleaf. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't know. The Overleaf links needs registration, but I tried it on v1 and it worked just fine (https://v1.overleaf.com/read/pmmbwvkgmwjw). Of course the field is not shown in the output, but that was expected.

Comment: So if it doesn't show in the output, what is the purpose of the field?

Comment: If you want an authoritative answer I guess you should contact http://inspirehep.net/ why they export that field. Their email is feedback@inspirehep.net, they also have a twitter account (https://twitter.com/inspirehep) if you have an account and like that sort of thing, but I'm not sure if they respond there.

Comment: If you decide to send them a mail, please let us know their response. If you don't want to send a mail, ping me, then I might consider asking them.

Comment: I wouldn't half mind you doing it.

Comment: I sent off a quick email. Will edit the answer when I hear back from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system a search for `SLACcitation` in `$TEXMF/bibtex/bst/` only turns up the REVTeX styles. On CTAN there is also [`chetref.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chet/chetref.bst), but the code for `SLACcitation` there is commented out. [SPIRES: BibTeX Style Files](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hep/refs/bibstyles.shtml) lists a few other styles.

[The REVTeX 4.1 announcement](https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/revtex/whatsnew4-1.pdf) mentions `SLACcitation` in association with arXiv support, but does not explain the use of the field further.

[SPIRES: BibTeX Style Files](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hep/refs/bibstyles.shtml) and [LaTeX Output and SPIRES citation gathering (Wayback machine snapshot from 2004-10-26)](https://web.archive.org/web/20041026075722/http://www.slac.stanford.edu:80/spires/hep/latex.html) as well as [BibTeX from SPIRES (Wayback machine snapshot from 2004-12-24)](https://web.archive.org/web/20041224151437/http://www.slac.stanford.edu:80/spires/hep/bibliotex.html) suggest that `SLACcitation` contains some kind of citation metadata that is/was used by [SPIRES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_Physics_Information_Retrieval_System) probably to track citations. (Cf. also http://www.inr.ac.ru/~fedor/jabref/spires2.3.patch)

All styles that support the field write it in a line of its own, so that an entry in the `.bbl` would look like (from [LaTeX Output and SPIRES citation gathering (Wayback machine snapshot from 2004-10-26)](https://web.archive.org/web/20041026075722/http://www.slac.stanford.edu:80/spires/hep/latex.html))

```
\bibitem{Morningstar:1997ff}
C.J.~Morningstar and M.~Peardon,
%``Efficient glueball simulations on anisotropic lattices,"
Phys. Rev. {\bf D56}, 4043 (1997)
hep-lat/9704011.
%%CITATION = PHRVA,D56,4043;%%
```

Due to the `%%` in front of the `CITATION` LaTeX would ignore the rest of the line and the `SLACcitation` field would produce no output in the bibliography. The tag is only visible in the source code. Indeed [LaTeX Output and SPIRES citation gathering (Wayback machine snapshot from 2004-10-26)](https://web.archive.org/web/20041026075722/http://www.slac.stanford.edu:80/spires/hep/latex.html) says

> Our program looks for the `%%CITATION` tag in your `.tex` file (which, of course, will not show up in the printed copy of your paper).

but does not go on to explain what exactly the program does. http://inspirehep.net/info/faq/references_citations also suggests that

As usual `SLACcitation` will be ignored by all styles where the field has not been declared. It is also ignored by (standard) `biblatex` (and all contributed styles I know), but if it were read by `biblatex` the `%%` would produce errors if the field was not read in verbatim mode.

Since there is no further documentation of the field and no other mentions on the web besides the meagre few sites mentioned above and a great many exported `.bib` entries, I doubt this field is very important, let alone required for REVTeX. [INSPIRE References and Citations: How can I ensure my references are fully extracted?](http://inspirehep.net/info/faq/references_citations#ensure_full_reference_extraction) refers to formats that output the `%%CITATION` metadata, but it is not clear to me from the rest of this site that the tag is a requirement.

---

I contacted INSPIRE about this. This is their prompt reply

> SPIRES (INSPIRE's predecessor) used to extract references for papers
>   from LaTeX sources. Putting a `%%CITATION = ...` comment in a
>   reference was a clever trick to make it easy to identify the cited
>   record without it affecting the typeset paper. That's why it appeared
>   in (and still does on INSPIRE) in the LaTeX export formats. For people
>   who were using BibTeX to handle their bibliography instead of getting
>   straight `bibitem`s from SPIRES, some additional trick was needed to
>   have bibtex output the proper comment: the `SLACcitation` field was
>   added to the BibTeX export format, so that a BibTeX style could just
>   pick up that field and put it somewhere in the reference to have it
>   recognized properly by SPIRES.
>
> As authors needed to do many things to make it work properly and
>   parsing TeX is hard, this method of recognizing references was
>   abandoned on INSPIRE. Instead, references are now extracted from the
>   PDF and citations identified by searching our records for potential
>   matches, based on identifiers (DOI, arXiv ID, etc.) and publication
>   information (journal title, volume, pages, etc.). We also try to match
>   the citation key (which appears in the PDF as a named destination when
>   `hyperref` is used), as the keys we expose in the LaTeX/BibTeX export
>   formats are unique identifiers for papers on INSPIRE. The `%%CITATION = ...` comment and assorted BibTeX field have survived until now, but will be removed in an upcoming update of INSPIRE as they are no longer
>   needed.

That more or less confirms the findings and speculations from above.

- `%%CITATION =` was used to identify citations without affecting the typeset output
- `SLACcitation` was used to produce `%%CITATION =` from `.bib` files
- nowadays `%%CITATION` and `SLACcitation` are not used any more